# How to get ADB status?

Tags: android, adb

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1393280) described how to switch on and switch off debugging via WiFi. Is there way to detect current status for this? I think I need to get current value of service.adb.tcp.port and check it on equals -1. But how to get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug via wifi you need to connect your device(phone/ tablet) to the same network as your pc. Get the device's ip from the advanced menu in Settings -> WiFi. Then use this to connect to the device:

```
adb connect deviceip
```

Now, when you use `adb devices`, you should see something like `deviceip:5555 device`.

UPDATE:
To truly answer your question: to get the value you are looking for just use this:

```
adb shell getprop service.adb.tcp.port
```